# Python selenium find_element_by_class_name.click not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, onclick

```
<button class="in chlodIng" onclick="Attendance.Dashboard.WeeklyData.updateCheckOut(true)">
```

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('out chlodIng').click()
```

The button should get clicked, am getting error:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".out chlodIng"}

Please let me know how to do it in a proper way. Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see no element matching `'out chlodIng'` class name on the picture

Answer (score 0):

**class name** does not work with `spaces`, I would probably suggest you to use the  below `css selector` with `Explicit waits :`

**sample code  :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick^='Attendance.Dashboard.WeeklyData.updateCheckOut']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: tried and I got error

  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick^='Attendance.Dashboard.WeeklyData.updateCheckOut']"))).click()
  File "/home/madhuraank/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='in chlodIng'][contains(.,'Check-in')]
```

Comment: Tried, got error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='in chlodIng'][contains(.,'Check-in')]"}

Comment: can you provide your url pls

Comment: https://peopleplus.zoho.in/60008324356/zp#home/dashboard